TensorFlow Keras compilation successful; still model summary is undefined
I am using the following code to define and compile a Keras model. Then when I print the model.summary() I am still getting unbuilt and erroneous summary. I am using Python3.10.12 and tensorflow 2.16.1. Please do not hesitate to reach out for any additional information you need.
Code to build the model
  model = Sequential()
  #model.add(embedding_layer)  # Add embedding layer if applicable
  model.add(Dense(num_dense_units, activation='relu'))  # First dense layer with ReLU activation
  model.add(Dense(len(set(cluster_labels)), activation='softmax'))  # Output layer with softmax for multi-class classification

  # Model compilation
  #model.compile(loss=CategoricalCrossentropy(), optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.compile(loss=CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
  print(model.summary())

Outcome of model.summary()
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                         ┃ Output Shape                ┃         Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ embedding (Embedding)                │ ?                           │     0 (unbuilt) │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_2 (Dense)                      │ ?                           │     0 (unbuilt) │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_3 (Dense)                      │ ?                           │     0 (unbuilt) │
└──────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
 Total params: 0 (0.00 B)
 Trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
None

When I run my script I get the following runtime error too, which I think is because the model is not being built correctly, as I verified other dimension related things and they are correct.
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/trainers/data_adapters/__init__.py", line 120, in get_data_adapter
    raise ValueError(f"Unrecognized data type: x={x} (of type {type(x)})")
ValueError: Unrecognized data type: x=[[ 0  0  0 ... 10  4  7]
 [ 0  0  0 ... 10  4  7]
 [ 0  0  0 ... 10  4  7]
 ...
 [ 0  0  0 ...  1  6 30]
 [ 0  0  0 ...  1  6 30]
 [ 0  0  0 ...  1  6 30]] (of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>)


What does the training data look like that you are using?

Read this: http://www.keras.io/guides/sequential_model, specially the "Specifying the input shape in advance" section

You need to properly define the input specification of the keras model in order to properly visualize the model summary. For your case, you need to define the input shape at the beginning. Here is a sample code.
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Embedding(
        input_dim=500, output_dim=128, input_shape=(100,)
    ),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=64, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax') 
])
model.summary() # OK

input_array = np.random.randint(
    500, size=(32, 100)
)
model(input_array).shape

Also note, the input_length is removed for embedding layer in keras 3 from 2. Here are some details. The above coed is tested in keras 3 (tf backend).
